# No annotations created for created entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

This could be a newbie question and in the documentation of Symfony I couldn't find it. I've installed Symfony according the docs and created a database using the 'database & doctrine' manual. After that I created an entity using the doctrine. When I did that I noticed that no annotions where created. As bundle I used the AppBundle which is also in my AppKernel like this:

```
$bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    ];
```

UPDATE:
Using the command `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity` I've created Entity Foo using annotation (instead of yml, php or xml) which resulted in this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FooRepository")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string", length=35)
     */
    private $bar;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set bar
     *
     * @param string $bar
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bar
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

So it also generated annotations but I still cannot generate my database schema :(

*Original question below is obsolete*
What is the reason I have to enter my annotations manually?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you're miss understanding how databases are created with Doctriine.

Entity classes (in `src/AppBundle/Entity/`) define, well, entities, that are mapped *tables*.

This classes have *properties* (aka. variables) which represent columns (or associations). This properties have to be annotated so that doctrine knows what kind of column to create.

Now these classes can be constructed entirely by hand *or* generated with the following command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

But you have to understand this is just a shortcut - you're still responsible to maintain and develop the schema.

So to answer your question:

> What is the reason I have to enter my annotations manually?

Because doctrine can not know what kind of data you want to save - annotations are a way for **you** to explain **to doctrine** (and symfony) what you need.

Don't forget to run `doctrine:schema:create` to actually create the tables described in your entities.

Comment: Oke, it is clear for me that entities are objects and that they refer to tables in my database. And yes indeed the properties are columns in their respective tables. So far I agree with you. I thought that well if doctrine also generates classes (entities) why it doesn't generate also it's annotations. I felt becoming lazy haha

Comment: Mhh well for some reason it also doesn't create my db schema. When I execute that command it returns just 'No metadata classes to process'... I have really no idea what is wrong with my setup. I've done everything according the manual http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: When using the command to generate the entity ... did you use "use annotations" or did you choose one of the other options (like yml). Also, did you add any fields?

Can you add the entire Entity class to your queston?

Comment: I've updated the question as requested with a foo entity

Comment: Ok, have you run `doctrine:schema:create` or `doctrine:schema:update --force`?

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I figured out the problem.

Using the interactive manual I overlooked the 'option' annotations. That was the first mistake I made.

The second mistake I made was that I was creating the entities in the build in AppBundle. When I created my own Bundle it all worked flawless :)